# How to stop an activity sending to directline webchat from React Js code

Tags: reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

How to stop an activity sending to ReactWebChat in React Js code, currently I am having an issue with the 4MB size limit upload, so I need to stop attachment activity when the user uploads more than 4MB size.
I know that `activitymiddleware` can be used for tracking activities sent to the bot from the user and vice versa. But I couldn't stop the activity from sending to the bot.

Answer (score 0):

When using the AcitivityMiddleware, there is always a `return next(action);` at the end. That means that the action is sent to the next handler. You might need to not call that method and return an action directly from that. Keep in mind that you need to post a message on your own using a similar approach to this sample:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event

Meaning your code should look something like this:

```
if ("action has size larger than 4 MB") { // I don't know the exact check
  dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
    payload: {
      name: 'webchat/fileLimit',
      value: { fileSize: "the file size" } // Send the file size as the value
    }
  });
}
```

Then, handle that activity:

```
if (context.activity.name === 'webchat/fileLimit') {
  await context.sendActivity(
    `Got \`webchat/fileLimit\` event, the file size is \`${(context.activity.value || {}).fileSize}\``
  );
}
```